# How to prevent or mitigate DOMS

Tags: diet, pain, muscle-soreness, doms, soreness

So I realize that [DOMS isn't really bad](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15826/doms-good-or-bad).  It comes from [working your muscles in a different way](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/40682/why-do-muscles-get-sore-after-workouts).  But assuming I'll be doing the same workout either way, is there a way I can prevent sore muscles?

I've been told in the past about potassium and bananas being good ways to help, but I can't say I've noticed a ton, and I'm wondering if that's just an old wives tale, or if there are other tips to preventing DOMS either before or after I work out.

Answer (score 2):

Stay consistent enough and DOMs will start diminishing over time. I personally don't really get them anymore after years. They'll be a minor inconvenience at worst if I do get them. The exception being is if I took a couple weeks off. I'll get then the first workout but they'll go away by the second.

Once you have them though, you just kind of have to deal with it. I've found the best way is to just move. Do some light dynamic stretching. If it's your legs, them simply walking helps. If it's in your arms, then some stretching can help. If it's *really* acute, you may have to take Ibuprofen or any NSAID painkiller. You should treat it as an injury at that point.

You can still workout with DOMs. Though you may have to back off on some workouts depending on severity, and do something light and easy if anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

I do still get DOMs from time to time, particularly after a long run (15kms and upwards). Walking and a proper cool down after a run always helps me, some light stretching also goes a long way.

Also... ABFR (always be [foam rolling](https://www.hfe.co.uk/blog/the-dos-and-donts-of-foam-rolling/))